# How do I install netfilterqueue for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnome-terminal

I am doing a project with python3.8 as my interpreter in pycharm.

How do I install netfilterqueue so that it works in python3? I have tried to run the following command in my kali terminal but I get the following error:

```
root@kali:~/PycharmProjects/dns_spoof# pip3 install netfilterqueue
Collecting netfilterqueue
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/c4/8f73f70442aa4094b3c37876c96cddad2c3e74c058f6cd9cb017d37ffac0/NetfilterQueue-0.8.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for netfilterqueue ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-evvln_9d/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-z72tnt4e --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'netfilterqueue' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netfilterqueue.o
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_set_nfq_data’:
  netfilterqueue.c:2150:68: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘nfq_get_payload’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   2150 |   __pyx_v_self->payload_len = nfq_get_payload(__pyx_v_self->_nfa, (&__pyx_v_self->payload));
        |                                                                   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                                                                    |
        |                                                                    char **
  In file included from netfilterqueue.c:440:
  /usr/include/libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h:122:67: note: expected ‘unsigned char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
    122 | extern int nfq_get_payload(struct nfq_data *nfad, unsigned char **data);
        |                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_4get_hw’:
  netfilterqueue.c:2533:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’; did you mean ‘PyBytes_FromStringAndSize’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                 PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
  netfilterqueue.c:2533:15: warning: assignment to ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
        |               ^
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyCFunction_FastCall’:
  netfilterqueue.c:6436:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))meth’
   6436 |     return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
        |            ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
  netfilterqueue.c:7132:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7132 |     *type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                     ^~~~~~~~
        |                     curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7133:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7133 |     *value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7134:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7134 |     *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                   curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
  netfilterqueue.c:7141:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7141 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                        ^~~~~~~~
        |                        curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7142:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7142 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                         ^~~~~~~~~
        |                         curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7143:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7143 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c:7144:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7144 |     tstate->exc_type = type;
        |             ^~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7145:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7145 |     tstate->exc_value = value;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7146:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7146 |     tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
  netfilterqueue.c:7201:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7201 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
        |                        ^~~~~~~~
        |                        curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7202:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7202 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
        |                         ^~~~~~~~~
        |                         curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7203:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7203 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
        |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |                      curexc_traceback
  netfilterqueue.c:7204:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
   7204 |     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
        |             ^~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_type
  netfilterqueue.c:7205:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
   7205 |     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_value
  netfilterqueue.c:7206:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
   7206 |     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
        |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
        |             curexc_traceback
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py clean for netfilterqueue
Failed to build netfilterqueue
Installing collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Running setup.py install for netfilterqueue ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-evvln_9d/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-7hb6tfdl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'netfilterqueue' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c netfilterqueue.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/netfilterqueue.o
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_set_nfq_data’:
    netfilterqueue.c:2150:68: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘nfq_get_payload’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     2150 |   __pyx_v_self->payload_len = nfq_get_payload(__pyx_v_self->_nfa, (&__pyx_v_self->payload));
          |                                                                   ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                                                                    |
          |                                                                    char **
    In file included from netfilterqueue.c:440:
    /usr/include/libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h:122:67: note: expected ‘unsigned char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
      122 | extern int nfq_get_payload(struct nfq_data *nfad, unsigned char **data);
          |                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_14netfilterqueue_6Packet_4get_hw’:
    netfilterqueue.c:2533:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’; did you mean ‘PyBytes_FromStringAndSize’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                 PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
    netfilterqueue.c:2533:15: warning: assignment to ‘PyObject *’ {aka ‘struct _object *’} from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     2533 |     __pyx_t_3 = PyString_FromStringAndSize(((char *)__pyx_v_self->hw_addr), 8); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 111, __pyx_L1_error)
          |               ^
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyCFunction_FastCall’:
    netfilterqueue.c:6436:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘(PyObject * (*)(PyObject *, PyObject * const*, Py_ssize_t))meth’
     6436 |     return (*((__Pyx_PyCFunctionFast)meth)) (self, args, nargs, NULL);
          |            ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
    netfilterqueue.c:7132:21: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7132 |     *type = tstate->exc_type;
          |                     ^~~~~~~~
          |                     curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7133:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7133 |     *value = tstate->exc_value;
          |                      ^~~~~~~~~
          |                      curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7134:19: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7134 |     *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
          |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                   curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
    netfilterqueue.c:7141:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7141 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
          |                        ^~~~~~~~
          |                        curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7142:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7142 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
          |                         ^~~~~~~~~
          |                         curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7143:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7143 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
          |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                      curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c:7144:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7144 |     tstate->exc_type = type;
          |             ^~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7145:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7145 |     tstate->exc_value = value;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7146:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7146 |     tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
    netfilterqueue.c:7201:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7201 |     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
          |                        ^~~~~~~~
          |                        curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7202:25: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7202 |     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
          |                         ^~~~~~~~~
          |                         curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7203:22: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7203 |     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
          |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                      curexc_traceback
    netfilterqueue.c:7204:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     7204 |     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
          |             ^~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_type
    netfilterqueue.c:7205:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     7205 |     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_value
    netfilterqueue.c:7206:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     7206 |     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
          |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |             curexc_traceback
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-evvln_9d/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-7hb6tfdl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-evvln_9d/netfilterqueue/
```

After the error I have tried to run "pip uninstall netfilterqueue" and "pip3 uninstall netfilterqueue" and then "pip3 install netfilterqueue" again but I still get the same error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I have tried that but the netfilterque installed only works for programs run in python2 interpreter. I have to use netfilterqueue in python3.8. How do I install netfilterqueue for for python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like NetfilterQueue package doesn't support python 3.7+. They don't provide such information on the site, but I tried building it and I got the same errors on 3.7, when it compiles fine for 3.6.

That would make sense because the pip package was released: Jan 31, 2017 and python3.7 on 2018.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, does it mean I have to downgrade to a python 3.6 interpreter in pycharm? If so how would I do that?

Comment: You need to downgrade only for this project. Install python3.6: `sudo apt install python3.6-dev python3.6-venv` if this won't work, add deadsnakes ppa: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. Set interpreter to 3.6 in your project. Pycharm > settings > project > python interpreter

Answer (score 2):

hello first install netfilterqueue on your linux machine

```
sudo apt install libnfnetlink-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev
```

then you should know netfilterqueue for python3+ is named nfqp3 so install it with

```
pip3 install nfqp3
```

it is worth mentioning that when importing it in a python script you should import it as netfilterqueue not nfqp3

Answer (score 1):

It worked after I installed this:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev`
2. `pip install NetfilterQueue` or `pip3 install NetfilterQueue`

My python3 version is 3.6.9

Answer (score 1):

The project is abandoned but there are forks that fix this issue.
https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/pull/60 especially upgrades netfilterqueue to build on modern Cython, allowing it to support Python > 3.6. You can try using that branch

```
pip install https://github.com/johnteslade/python-netfilterqueue/archive/refs/heads/update-cython-code.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

you will find the solution here :

https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/issues/53

Specially this answer :

> `pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue`