# Problem Installing netfilterque in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem installing netfilterqueue for Python. I have this logs.

[image]

I am using Windows 10, not Linux, and Python 3.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've supplied both a short answer, and a longer explanation of it.

**Short Answer**
Unfortunately, the project seems to be abandoned after it only working with Python2. As a result, many people decided to downgrade to python2 to continue using it. However, forking a repo on GitHub fixed it for a while. However, the original person decided to stop updating it on GitHub.

Oremanj decided to take over  maintainership of the project and keep it from going under. So, to install the fork that seems to work you would run this in terminal:

```
pip install cython
git clone https://github.com/oremanj/python-netfilterqueue
cd python-netfilterqueue
pip install .
```

**Long Answer**
There seems to be a lot of issues with getting it to work with python3 + scapy has the same issue with py3.

It seems like it works with python2. However, I am only referencing a thread that I found on the topic.

[Referenced Here](https://forum.stationx.net/t/netfilterqueue-import-error/3662)

However, I dug more into the topic and the issue and it seems like on the website it states that it works for python 3.6 and above.

It seems like it was abandoned: [Referenced here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301351/how-do-i-install-netfilterqueue-for-python3)

I am mainly focusing on Cukic0d's answer to this question:

> The project is abandoned but there are forks that fix this issue. https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/pull/60 especially upgrades netfilterqueue to build on modern Cython, allowing it to support Python > 3.6. You can try using that branch.

However, even looking at the GitHub it seemed like it was also abandoned. HOWEVER, it looks like oremanj on GitHub took over maintainership of the project: [Referenced Here.](https://github.com/oremanj/python-netfilterqueue/pull/60)

> I've taken over maintainership of this project and just pushed an update. Will release to PyPI shortly; in the meantime you can pip install Git+https://github.com/oremanj/python-netfilterqueue.

I've never used netfilterqueue before. However, this is just some digging I did to hopefully get you a solution to this problem. If it still does not work let me know, and I'll dig further into what may be causing the issue.

Other solutions if it does not work I've referenced:

- Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required, and you must install build visual tools 15, 17, 19 or greater. [Download Here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) (This seems to not work for a lot of people, but it's worth a try) -- [Referenced Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-problem-with)
- Some people faced the same problem running the installation of it like this:

`python -m pip install package-name`

After many failed attempts, Lucas found that running it like this solved the issue:

`py -m pip install package-name`

He says that he gets two different python's one that is 3.9.8 and one that is 3.8.2: [Referenced Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-problem-with)

Comment: Hi, for me not work but with the explanation its clear for me. I see that I can't use it with python 3, so I'll look for an alternative. Thank you!